# Rolling Window based on a fixed time interval

Tags: r, datetime, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate a rolling window in a fixed time interval. Suppose that the interval is 48 hours. I would like to get every data point that is contained between the date of the current observation and 48 hours before that observation. For example, if the datetime of the current observation is `05-07-2022 14:15:28`, for that position, I would like a count value for every occurence between that date and `03-07-2022 14:15:28`. Seconds are not fundamental to the analysis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = tibble(id = 1:7,
            date_time = ymd_hm('2022-05-07 15:00', '2022-05-09 13:45', '2022-05-09 13:51', '2022-05-09 17:00',
                               '2022-05-10 15:25', '2022-05-10 17:18', '2022-05-11 14:00'))


# A tibble: 7 × 2
     id date_time          
  <int> <dttm>             
1     1 2022-05-07 15:00:00
2     2 2022-05-09 13:45:00
3     3 2022-05-09 13:51:00
4     4 2022-05-09 17:00:00
5     5 2022-05-10 15:25:00
6     6 2022-05-10 17:18:00
7     7 2022-05-11 14:00:00
```

With the example window of 48 hours, that would yield:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
     id date_time           lag_48hours         count
  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>
1     1 2022-05-07 15:00:00 2022-05-05 15:00:00     1
2     2 2022-05-09 13:45:00 2022-05-07 13:45:00     2
3     3 2022-05-09 13:51:00 2022-05-07 13:51:00     3
4     4 2022-05-09 17:00:00 2022-05-07 17:00:00     3
5     5 2022-05-10 15:25:00 2022-05-08 15:25:00     4
6     6 2022-05-10 17:18:00 2022-05-08 17:18:00     5
7     7 2022-05-11 14:00:00 2022-05-09 14:00:00     4
```

I added the lag column for illustration purposes. Any idea how to obtain the count column? I need to be able to adjust the window (48 hours in this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd encourage you to use [slider](https://slider.r-lib.org/), which allows you to do rolling window analysis using an irregular index.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(slider)

df = tibble(
  id = 1:7,
  date_time = ymd_hm(
    '2022-05-07 15:00', '2022-05-09 13:45', '2022-05-09 13:51', '2022-05-09 17:00',
    '2022-05-10 15:25', '2022-05-10 17:18', '2022-05-11 14:00'
  )
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    count = slide_index_int(
      .x = id, 
      .i = date_time, 
      .f = length, 
      .before = dhours(48)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>      id date_time           count
#>   <int> <dttm>              <int>
#> 1     1 2022-05-07 15:00:00     1
#> 2     2 2022-05-09 13:45:00     2
#> 3     3 2022-05-09 13:51:00     3
#> 4     4 2022-05-09 17:00:00     3
#> 5     5 2022-05-10 15:25:00     4
#> 6     6 2022-05-10 17:18:00     5
#> 7     7 2022-05-11 14:00:00     4
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well. I'll accept this answer because I think it's helpful if you don't want to write your own function.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
df %>% 
  mutate(count48 = map_int(date_time, 
                           ~sum(date_time <= . & date_time > . - 48 * 60 * 60)))

# A tibble: 7 × 3
     id date_time           count48
  <int> <dttm>                <int>
1     1 2022-05-07 15:00:00       1
2     2 2022-05-09 13:45:00       2
3     3 2022-05-09 13:51:00       3
4     4 2022-05-09 17:00:00       3
5     5 2022-05-10 15:25:00       4
6     6 2022-05-10 17:18:00       5
7     7 2022-05-11 14:00:00       4
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I was actually leaning towards using the map function, I just really wasn't sure how to go about it.